# Xcode 12 beta 6 cannot find my SPM architecture

Tags: swift-package-manager, xcode12beta6

I'm trying to load my app with the new xcode 12 beta 6 and i'm getting the following.

```
Could not find module 'MySwiftPackage' for target 'arm64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: x86_64-apple-ios-simulator, x86_64
```

As you can see, I have created an SPM which the system cannot find the correct architecture for. After searching a solution I came up with this:
https://medium.com/@purnenduroy07/could-not-find-module-for-target-x86-64-apple-ios-simulator-dbc676f131b1

But this guide refers to frameworks. When I build my SPM it doesn't give me a framework. The best I got is:

1. MySwiftPackage.o
2. MySwiftPackage.swiftmodule

I'm not sure if that could help me or not, or if i'm going the wrong way here.

Thanks for your help

Comment: did you manage to find a solution? I see the same issue, and we are now out of betas